# Use CSS to add a close X in this element

Tags: css

Is there a way to add and X to this element via CSS?

```
<span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
```

Im not sure where its located in the site, so Id rather just go this route

Comment: You could use a pseudo element, either `:before`, or `:after` to insert some content, such as "[x]" using something like `mobile_menu_bar_toggle:after { display:inline-block; content: '[x]'; }`.... You'd need to of course position it etc, but taht would be where i would start.

Comment: @Stuart You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo element:

```css
.mobile_menu_bar:after {
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:before` pseudo-element

```
span.mobile_menu_bar:before {
   content: "X";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8abpgm33/2/